# "Table" option for package "xcolor" gets "Use of @startpbox doesn't match its definition."

Tags: color

I am getting the following error during compilation: "Use of @startpbox doesn't match its definition."

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=6mm,includehead,left=1.5cm,bottom=2cm,right=1.5cm,headsep=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\usepackage{graphicx}


\usepackage{csvsimple}

\usepackage{multirow}  

\usepackage{scalerel,amssymb}
\def\msquare{\mathord{\scalerel*{\Box}{gX}}}



\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{many}
\usepackage{fancybox} % for ovalbox + fancybox.sty



%-----------    HEADER  AND  FOOTER      -----------------------------------------


\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.2pt} % linha no footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.2pt}% linha no header 


\pagestyle{fancy} 

\fancypagestyle{firststyle}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
  \lhead{%
    \def\scale{0.6}%
    \def\roundc{\scale*0.1cm}% rc = 10% de sc
    \raisebox{-2\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\scale]
      \definecolor{tempcolor}{RGB}{200,25,30}
      \filldraw[tempcolor][rounded corners=\roundc] (2cm,0cm) rectangle (1.2cm,-0.5cm);
      \filldraw[tempcolor][rounded corners=\roundc] (2cm,-0.6cm) rectangle (1.1cm,-1.1cm);
      \filldraw[tempcolor][rounded corners=\roundc] (2cm,-0.6cm) rectangle (1.5cm,-1.1cm);
      \filldraw[tempcolor][rounded corners=\roundc] (1.7cm,-1.2cm) rectangle (1.2cm,-1.7cm);
      \filldraw[tempcolor][rounded corners=\roundc] (0.6cm,-1.2cm) rectangle (1.1cm,-1.7cm);
      \filldraw[tempcolor][rounded corners=\roundc] (1.6cm,-1.2cm) rectangle (1.8cm,-1.7cm);
      \filldraw[tempcolor][rounded corners=\roundc] (1.7cm,-1.8cm) rectangle (1.2cm,-2.3cm);
      \node[scale=\scale,fill=white] at (5.92,-0.85) {\resizebox{6.7cm}{0.5cm}{\sffamily \textbf{ESCOLA}}};
      \node[scale=\scale,fill=white] at (4.52,-1.55) {\resizebox{5cm}{0.5cm}{\sffamily {Construindo o Futuro}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}}
  }
  \chead{\raisebox{-2\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\rule[-2.5\baselineskip]{\linewidth}{1.2pt}}}
  \rhead{\raisebox{-2\baselineskip}[0pt][0pt]{\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}}
    \tikz \node at (0,0) {\textbf{Final Exam}};\\ 
    \tikz[baseline]{\node[anchor=base, draw=black, thick, minimum width=8.5cm,
    minimum height=7mm,rounded corners, yshift=-2mm,label={[fill=white,label
    distance=-2mm,inner xsep=2pt]90:{\ttfamily Name}:}] {Teste};}   
    \tikz[baseline]{\node[anchor=base, draw=black, thick, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=7mm,rounded corners, yshift=-2mm,label={[fill=white,label distance=-2mm,inner xsep=2pt]90:{\ttfamily Turma}:}] {\phantom{\ttfamily 15,0}};}   
    \tikz[baseline]{\node[anchor=base, draw=black, thick, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=7mm,rounded corners, yshift=-2mm,label={[fill=white,label distance=-2mm,inner xsep=2pt]90:{\ttfamily Valor}:}] {\ttfamily 15,0};} 
    \tikz[baseline]{\node[anchor=base, draw=black, thick, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=7mm,rounded corners, yshift=-2mm,label={[fill=white,label distance=-2mm,inner xsep=2pt]90:{\ttfamily Nota}:}] {\phantom{\ttfamily 15,0}};}
    \end{tabular}}
  }
  \lfoot{\ttfamily Prof.\ Marcos}
  \rfoot{\ttfamily \today}
}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \thispagestyle{firststyle}
  \vspace*{2\baselineskip}
}


%-----------    HEADER  AND  FOOTER      -----------------------------------------




\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{students.csv}
name
Disco Dingo
Cosmic Cuttlefish
Bionic Beaver
\end{filecontents*}





\begin{document}


\def\obfmat{
\begin{center}
\tcbset{
        enhanced,
        colback=white,%red!5!white,
        boxrule=0.5pt,
        colframe=black!75!white,%red!75!black,
        fonttitle=\bfseries
       }
\begin{tcolorbox}[title={\sffamily\center TITLE BOX}, %
                   width=.95\linewidth, lifted shadow={1mm}{-2mm}{3mm}{0.1mm}%, halign=left,
                  {black!50!white}, boxsep=0mm, arc=3mm]
\vspace{1pt}
{
TEXT 
}
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{center}
}





\obfmat

  \rowcolors{4}{white}{gray!15}
\section*{Class 1}
    {
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c}%
   {\bfseries Name} & I will do &  When
    \csvreader[head to column names,
    ]{students.csv}{}% use head of csv as column names
    {\\ \hline  \name   & Yes $\msquare$ \quad No $\msquare$ &  }\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    }


\newpage 
\thispagestyle{firststyle}
  \vspace*{2\baselineskip}
  \vspace*{0.15cm} 


\obfmat

\rowcolors{4}{white}{gray!15}

\section*{Class 2}
    {
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c}%
   {\bfseries Name} & I will do &  When
    \csvreader[head to column names,
    ]{students.csv}{}% use head of csv as column names
    {\\ \hline  \name   & Yes $\msquare$ \quad No $\msquare$ &  }\\
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
    }

\end{document}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The example as posted compiled for me. I think I remember similar error messages due to an update a while ago. Are you sure all of your packages a fully up to date? If you are using MikTeX did you update in both admin *and* user mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with @moewe's comment. Probably it will solve your problem.

However, I took the liberty of providing some off-topic suggestions (see MWE below):

- It is sensible to define common styles for nodes and paths in your `tikzpicture`s .
- `\rowcolors{4}{white}{gray!15}` is good to have in group with tables, otherwise it makes unexpected coloring in document (for example in page headers).
- Instead `def` is better to use LaTeX macro `\newcommand` (it checks for the existence of the command with the same name).
- For names after each section is sensible to write a new command, for example `\newcommand\Names{....}`.
- `tcolorbox` loads the `tikz` and `xcolor` packages so you do not need to load them again. To have the `table` option available in `xcolor`, add `table` to the document class options.
- For nicer `firststyle` header styles I suggest rewriting the `geometry` package settings (see MWE below).
- For making `tikz` code shorter, I would use two TikZ libraries: `chains` and `positioning`.

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,table]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=5.5\baselineskip,
            headheight=5\baselineskip,%includehead,
            left=1.5cm,bottom=2cm,right=1.5cm,
            headsep=3mm]{geometry}
%\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{scalerel,amssymb}
\def\msquare{\mathord{\scalerel*{\Box}{gX}}}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{many}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                positioning}
\tikzset{baseline,
     node distance = 1mm,
       start chain = going right,
   box/.style args = {#1/#2}{draw, thick, rounded corners,
                      minimum width=#1, minimum height=9mm,
                      outer sep=0pt,
                      label=above:{#2:},
                      on chain, anchor=west},
every label/.style = {label distance=-2mm,
                      fill= white, inner xsep=2pt, font=\ttfamily}
        }
%-------------- HEADER  AND  FOOTER ----------------------------------
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.2pt} % linha no footer
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1.2pt} % linha no header
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancypagestyle{firststyle}%
    {\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}% Remove header rule
  \lhead{%
    \def\scale{0.6}%
    \def\roundc{\scale*0.1cm}% rc = 10% de sc
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\scale,
    every path/.style = {tempcolor,rounded corners=\roundc},
    every node/.style = {scale=\scale,fill=white,font=\sffamily}
                        ]
      \definecolor{tempcolor}{RGB}{200,25,30}
      \filldraw (2cm,0cm) rectangle (1.2cm,-0.5cm);
      \filldraw (2cm,-0.6cm) rectangle (1.1cm,-1.1cm);
      \filldraw (1.7cm,-1.2cm) rectangle (1.2cm,-1.7cm);
      \filldraw (0.6cm,-1.2cm) rectangle (1.1cm,-1.7cm);
      \filldraw (1.6cm,-1.2cm) rectangle (1.8cm,-1.7cm);
      \filldraw (1.7cm,-1.8cm) rectangle (1.2cm,-2.3cm);
      \node at (5.92,-0.85) {\resizebox{6.7cm}{0.5cm}{\textbf{ESCOLA}}};
      \node at (4.52,-1.55) {\resizebox{5cm}{0.5cm}{Construindo o Futuro}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
        }
  \chead{\rule[-8\baselineskip]{\linewidth}{1.2pt}}
  \rhead{\raisebox{-5.5\baselineskip}{%
    \begin{tabular}{@{} r @{}}
    \textbf{Final Exam}           \\
   \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[box=8.5cm/Name]   {Teste};
    \node[box=2.0cm/Turma]  {15,0};
    \node[box=1.5cm/Valor]  {15,0};
    \node[box=1.5cm/Nota]  {15,0};
      \end{tikzpicture}%
    \end{tabular}}
        }
  \lfoot{\ttfamily Prof.\ Marcos}
  \rfoot{\ttfamily \today}
}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \thispagestyle{firststyle}
  \vspace*{2\baselineskip}
                }
 %-------------- HEADER  AND  FOOTER ----------------------------------

\newcommand\obfmat{\begin{center}
\tcbset{
        enhanced,
        colback=white,%red!5!white,
        boxrule=0.5pt,
        colframe=black!75!white,%red!75!black,
        fonttitle=\bfseries
       }
\begin{tcolorbox}[title={\sffamily\center TITLE BOX}, %
                  width=.95\linewidth,
                  lifted shadow={1mm}{-2mm}{3mm}{0.1mm}%, halign=left,
                                {black!50!white}, boxsep=1pt, arc=3mm]
{TEXT}
\end{tcolorbox}
            \end{center}
}
\newcommand\Names{{
\rowcolors{4}{white}{gray!15}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c}%
   {\bfseries Name} & I will do &  When
    \csvreader[head to column names,
              ]{students.csv}{}% use head of csv as column names
    {\\ \hline
        \name   & Yes $\msquare$ \quad No $\msquare$ &  }\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}
    }}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{students.csv}
name
Disco Dingo
Cosmic Cuttlefish
Bionic Beaver
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\obfmat

\section*{Class 1}
\Names

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{firststyle}
\obfmat
`tc
\section*{Class 2}
\Names
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\end{document}
```

Comment: Where is the MWE below?

Comment: ups, i was convinced that i upload the code :-(.  i must search if i still have it somewhere in my editor ...

Comment: However, you got 3 upvotes and the OP accepted even without it :):):)

Comment: @CarLaTeX, thank you very much for note me!. Code is added, but now I'am completely confused ...

Comment: 4th upvote :):):):)